# Querying Subdocuments in MongoDb Documents and Only Return Matching Subdocuments

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Ive looked here: https://codelikethis.com/lessons/db/mongodb-array-queries and here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-query-an-array-of-sub-documents-in-mongodb/115315 to try and figure out how to query only matching subdocuments from a parent document.

Here is an example of the data:

```
{'testname':'process',
'jobId':"job1",
"vt_cond":"cond1",
"testData":[{
'chip':'c1',
'name':'block1'},
{
'chip':'c1',
'name':'block1'},
{
'chip':'c1',
'name':'block2'},
{
'chip':'c1',
'name':'block3'}]}
```

It contains subdocuments within the "testData" field. What I want to do is something like the following:

```
db.collection.find({'jobId':'job1', 'testData.name':'block3'})
```

and have it return the following:

```
{'testname':'process',
'jobId':"job1",
"vt_cond":"cond1",
"testData":[{'chip':'c1',
'name':'block3'}]}
```

I *understand* that the mongodb documentation states it will query and return a document which matches the conditions in the subdocument query conditions. It does. I get the entire example document as above. *Is there anyway where I can make a similar query with similar conditions as above, and only return the parent node with the desired subdocument, instead of ALL the subdocuments?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: You can use $elemMatch in the project part as follow:**

```
db.collection.find({
  "jobId": "job1",
  "testData.name": "block3"
},
{
 "testData": {
   "$elemMatch": {
      name: "block3"
  }
}
})
```

Explained:

Find the object and project only the array sub-object that match the criteria

Attention: This is only working if you need only 1x matching element from array , if there is more then one element in the array matching the criteria better use Option 2.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qjPkQ393PJI)

**Option 2: aggregate/$filter ( cover the case when you have more then one objects in the array matching by the filter )**

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
 {
  $match: {
  "jobId": "job1",
  "testData.name": "block3"
  }
 },
 {
  "$addFields": {
   "testData": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$testData",
      "as": "t",
      "cond": {
        $eq: [
          "$$t.name",
          "block3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Match the document
2. Filter only the matching objects inside the array of objects

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dH7r7na7dmX)

Comment: thank you! I will need to check the documentation with the "$addField" operator. Just a quick question @R2D2, there is an additional field I usually use in ".find({<query>},{_id:0}) to drop the _id object in the original query. Do you know how to do this in the aggregation pipeline? I can drop from the parent node by using the $project operation, is it a similar flow for subdocuments?

Comment: $addFields is very similar to $project  but in this case it is used  to replace the testData original field with the new version with filtered sub-objects ...